# Why don’t Save order and order_detail in database in PHP

Tags: php

I have.

Function setQuery

```
protected function setQuery($sql,$insert=FALSE)
{
    if($insert=TRUE)
    {
        var_dump($this->conn->query($sql));
        die();
        if($this->conn->query($sql)==TRUE)
        {
            $last_id=$this->conn->insert_id;
            return  $last_id;
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->conn->query($sql);
    }
   
}
```

Function oder_insert

```
function order_insert($data,$insert)
{
    $strf = "";
    $strv = "";
    foreach ($data as $f => $v) {
        $strf .= $f . ", ";
        $strv .= "'$v', ";
    }
    $strf = rtrim(rtrim($strf), ',');
    $strv = rtrim(rtrim($strv), ',');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table($strf) VALUES ($strv)";
    $this->setQuery($sql,$insert);
}
```

Function oder_details

```
function orderdetail_insert($data)
    {
        $strf = "";
        $strv = "";
        foreach ($data as $f => $v) {
            $strf .= $f . ", ";
            $strv .= "'$v', ";
        }
        $strf = rtrim(rtrim($strf), ',');
        $strv = rtrim(rtrim($strv), ',');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table($strf) VALUES ($strv)";
        $this->setQuery($sql);
    }
```

When checkout product

```
if(isset($_POST['CHECKOUT'])){
$data_order=array(
    'code'=>date('YmdHis'),
    'userid'=>$userid,
    'createdate'=>date('Y-m-d'),
    'exportdate'=>date('Y-m-d'),
    'deliveryaddress'=>(strlen($_POST['deliveryaddress']))?$_POST['deliveryaddress']:$row_account['address'],
    'deliveryname'=>(strlen($_POST['deliveryname']))?$_POST['deliveryname']:$row_account['fullname'],
    'deliveryphone'=>(strlen($_POST['deliveryphone']))?$_POST['deliveryphone']:$row_account['phone'],
    'deliveryemail'=>(strlen($_POST['deliveryemail']))?$_POST['deliveryemail']:$row_account['email'],
    'updated_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'updated_by'=>$userid,
    'status'=>2
);
$orderid=$order->order_insert($data_order,$insert=TRUE);
if($orderid!=null)
{
    foreach($cart_list as $cart_row)
    {
        $data_orderdetail=array(
            'orderid'=>$orderid,
            'productid'=>$cart_row['id'],
            'price'=>$cart_row['price'],
            'quantity'=>$cart_row['qty'],
            'amount'=>$cart_row['amount']
        );
        $orderdetail->orderdetail_insert($data_orderdetail);
    }
}
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
redirect('index.php');
```

}

When I order a product, I check out it. and It will start run to insert order and order details in the database. It doesn't give any error. When I debug I see that it's disconnected from the database and I don't understand why does it lose connection?
I'm sure the query is correct
Please explain it help me!

Comment: _...When I debug I see that it's disconnected from the database..._ How do you debug and how exactly do you know it is disconnected? However you should change `if($insert=TRUE)` to  `if($insert==true)` or just `if($insert)`

Comment: I put debug before " if($this->conn->query($sql)==TRUE) " from which I know this query is false.

Comment: I tried it as you said but it doesn't work